# Inner product preserving mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ be positive definite symmetric (pds) matrices.
For a matrix $M_1, M_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, 
I would like to know that under what conditions of $A$ and $B$, 
the following would be true?

(Previous)
$$
\langle AM_1B, M_2 \rangle_F = \langle M_1, M_2 \rangle_F,
$$
where $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_F$ is the frobenius inner product.

---

(Edited)
$$
\langle AM_1B, M_2 \rangle_F \ge \sigma^2_{\min}(A)\sigma_{\min}^2(B)\langle M_1, M_2 \rangle_F,
$$
where $\sigma_{\min}(A)$ is the smallest singular value of $A$.

---

Naively, since $A$ and $B$ are pds matrices, they are considered as sort of positive numbers.
Obviously, when $m=n=1$, the above is true with equality.

Any answers/suggestions/comments would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It may be helpful to observe that if we define $x_j = \operatorname{vec}(M_j)$ for $j = 1,2$ where vec denotes the [vectorization operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)), then we have
$$
\langle AM_1 B, M_2 \rangle_F = x_1^T (B \otimes A) x_2
$$